# SQL to get the first occurence of a value in each column within grouped elements

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I am bulding a report using SQL Server and Reporting Services. I have a dataset that looks something like the following where all columns are of type `VARCHAR`:

```
Line    Code    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
============================================
1       xxx     1.1                     
1       xxx             2.3             
1       xxx                     8.7     
1       xxx                             3.4
2       yyy     5.3                     
2       yyy             !err            
2       yyy                     6.5     
2       yyy                             9.1
```

I have a report that should have an output like this:

```
Line    Code    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
============================================
1       xxx     1.1     2.3     8.7     3.4
2       yyy     5.3     !err    6.5     9.1
```

So I basically need to perform a grouping on the "Line" column including the first non-empty values from each column within the group.

If the columns had been of a numeric type I could have used SUM to get to the desired outcome, but since I am dealing with `VARCHAR` I cannot use `SUM`. I can also not convert the `VARCHAR` to a numeric value because then, if my value is a non-numeric value (such as is suggested by "!err" in my example) then it won't be displayed.

What query can I use to get the desired outcome?

Comment: Although your sample data doesn't show it, can there be multiple values for a given line and coln? And can there be multiple codes for a given line?

Comment: No, for each "line" value, there will only ever appear ONE non-empty value in each column. And there will also not be multiple "code" values for each "line" value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there can only be one col-n values for a given line/code, this will work for you:

```
select
    line,
    code,
    max(col1) col1,
    max(col2) col2,
    max(col3) col3,
    max(col4) col4
from mytable
group by line, code
```

Comment: This won't give a desired result, you need to remove aggregate on `Code` column and include it in the GROUP BY: `GROUP BY Line, Code`.

Comment: @dimt I see your point. You are probably right - I'll make that change

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
declare @t table (line int, code varchar(4), c1 varchar(5), c2 varchar(5), c3 varchar(5), c4 varchar(5))

insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values (1, 'xxx', '1.5', '', '', '')
insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values  (1, 'xxx', '', 'err!', '', '')
insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values  (1, 'xxx', '', '', '2.3', '')
insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values  (1, 'xxx', '', '', '', '3.5')

insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values (2, 'yyy', '1.2', '', '', '')
insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values  (2, 'yyy', '', '0.8', '', '')
insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values  (2, 'yyy', '', '', 'err!', '')
insert into @t (line, code, c1, c2, c3, c4) values  (2, 'yyy', '', '', '', '4.6')

/* IF only one value in each column for a given code */
SELECT M1.Line, M1.Code 
, (SELECT c1 as cc FROM @t WHERE code = M1.code AND c1 <> '') as c1
, (SELECT c2 as cc FROM @t WHERE code = M1.code AND c2 <> '') as c2
, (SELECT c3 as cc FROM @t WHERE code = M1.code AND c3 <> '') as c3
, (SELECT c4 as cc FROM @t WHERE code = M1.code AND c4 <> '') as c4
FROM @t M1
GROUP BY M1.Line, M1.Code
```